# SQL Query - Fetch all Columns in a table but also assign aliases to the Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have been do loads of Google Searches looking for an answer to this and can't seem to find anything.

Basically I have a CheckedListbox in the program I'm try to create which will contain security privileges which can be assigned to a group. These privileges are stored against the groups record in my database.

[image: My Group Table]

An example of what I would like returned would be

- Create Records
- Edit Records
- Delete Records

Instead of:

- createRecs
- editRecs
- deleteRecs

I found this SQL Query which would pull out the tables columns but with there raw names which isn't what I want.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'
```

### Solution

I know this isn't the best way of doing it but here is what I came up with:

1. Do a standard SELECT query to retrieve the TOP(0)

   ```
               SELECT TOP(0) createRecs as 'Create Records',
                editRecs as 'Edit Records',
                viewRecs as 'View Records',
                deleteRecs as 'Delete Records',
                payRecs as 'Record Payment Options',
                archiveRecs as 'Archive Records',
                viewReports as 'View Reports',
                exportRecs as 'Export Records',
                manageUsers as 'Manage User Accounts',
                createUser as 'Create Users',
                editUser as 'Edit Users',
                deleteUser as 'Delete Users',
                resetPass as 'Reset User Passowrd',
                disableUser as 'Enable/Disable Users Accounts',
                createGroup as 'Create Groups',
                editGroup as 'Edit Groups',
                deleteGroup as 'Delete Groups'
               FROM db_membership
   ```
2. This then give me a DataTable in VB.net which contains no data, but it does contain the Column Headers I have set as Aliases.
3. Now I loop through the DataTable with the following code in VB.net to get each column header and put it in my checkedlistbox.

   ```
   dt = New DataTable
   dt = SQL.fetchSecurityOptions(login.Secure.username)
   For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
       create_securityOptions_chklist.Items.Add(column.ColumnName)
   Next
   ```
4. Here is the result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFMV3.png)

Comment: So you want to ALIAS the VALUES returned in COLUMN_NAME?

Comment: Yes you got it. I need some sort of Query that would allow me to do that. @scsimon

Comment: That isn't a job for SQL and kind of defeats the purpose of the query. You could just hard code it... but if you insist on this approach i'd pull it into an array within your application and handle it there. Can I ask why? Sorry but i'm baffled.

Comment: @scsimon - I have edited my post with my reason

Comment: You will always have to hard code it, whether it's in your VB app or SQL so i'd keep it in VB where 99% of your stuff will be maintained. Luckily, columns aren't usually added to tables that often though in your case it may be. If your columns were something simple like RemoveGroups and you wanted just add a space that'd be more manageable with SQL functions, but it'd apply to EVERY value.

Comment: Speaking of this actually I could do a SQL Select that selects say 1 row from the table and I apply the aliases to each column and then do a loop through the datatable in vb which gets the column names. That then keeps it all in a SQL procedure. Obviously it isn't great but should allow me to get what I want, wouldn't you say?

Comment: But as you add new columns to the table you'll still have to alias them, thus not reducing your maintenance right?

Comment: True, but if I added more columns I would have to maintain all the procedure that rely on them therefore meaning I don't have to update my program everytime. I know its not ideal but I think it'll work for what I need. Thank You @scsimon for helping me think.

Comment: No worries. You could look into PIVOT BUT I really am not sure if it will work for you. GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT createRecs as [Create Records], editRecs as [Edit Records] FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'membership'
```

Comment: @RacilHilan double quotes are fine but single quotes are for strings

Comment: @Brad Interesting argument. So are you saying that single quotes don't work? Or that they work but not recommended? Because as far as I know, they worked in every database engine I've used. Here is a [demo in SQL Server](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/509602/644777/)

Comment: @RacilHilan I was saying not recommended but then again neither is spaces in the name in general for the mere fact that when you reference it later you'd have to enclose it in quotes or brackets. More common not to use spaces at all, but use underscores, camel case, etc. Of course this gets nastier depending on if you have QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON or OFF.

Comment: OK, now "not recommended" is NOT a solution. You can add it to his question as a comment if you like, but to say that it is a solution, it actually doesn't solve any problem because single quotes work. So the real question now is "What is the OP's issue?".

Comment: @RacilHilan oh interesting. I guess I just never did that because it was odd using single quotes for double duty like that. But you are right.

Comment: @RacilHilan check the OP's post. They edited it, making this a solution. Cheers

Comment: Yes, agree. As it stands now, your answer is the solution to his question, but with the original post, the OP seemed to know the answer and how to use the aliases, so I have no idea what his issue was.

Comment: You haven't answered my question at all! I know how to get Columns out of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA the problem is they come out in there short names of createRecs, editRecs, etc... What I want is a query that pulls them out but allows me to put an alias on each which that query can't do as it has to stay as follows:   >SELECT *
FROM Northwind.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Customers'

Comment: This is due to the * indicating all columns from the table name 'x'

Answer (score 0):

WHERE Table_Name = 'membership'

I don't believe you don't need the N, but I could be wrong, I'm fairly new to SQL.

Comment: The `N` at the start of the string signifies it is a unicode string. not necessary in this instance but sometimes it is.